# Print numbers between 0 and 999 with interval of 4 with Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I got this code in my Python IDE and am trying to make it print out all the integers between 0 and 999 at interval of 4 like this,`4,8,12,16,20,24` and so on but it seems like the logic am using got a bug, please help me fix it...Its printing out `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...` to the console

```
p=999
for i in range(1,p):
        i=i+4#increment value with 4
        print(f"{i}")
```

Comment: Maybe use the third argument to range()?

Comment: There is a third argument for range?:))

Comment: Yes, you can specify a step size.

Comment: Got it, its the `step` argument. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function takes an optional third parameter `step`, which is exactly what you need:

```py
step = 4
p = 999
for i in range(0, p, step):
        print(i)
```

Will give the output `0, 4, 8, 12, ...`.

Change to `range(4, p, step)` to get the output `4, 8, 12, ...`.

Credits to the commenter @Mark M